# Magento ver. 2.4.1 : Can we get order data in Balance Class?

Tags: magento2, store-credit

Is their any way we can get order data
`Magento\CustomerBalance\Model\Balance` class

In local environment on protected function `_ensureCustomer`() method i get order data by `$this->getOrder()` but in live it causes error, i am not sure if `$this->getOrder()` method exist for this class and in `_ensureCustomer()` method.

Any advice or thoughts ?

Comment: The issue is in my local i get data by using $this->getOrder()->getId();
but in production environment i am not getting data but error Call to a member function getOrder() on null.

Comment: I need some advice on this.

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?